# Device specific OpenGL ES implementation functions

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to find the device specific OpenGL ES function implementations but for the life of me, and grep, I cannot seem to located them.

I am using an Android 4.4.4 embedded system running a 3.10.9 kernel. I am looking to find the device specific implementations of the OpenGL API entry points, defined by `EGL_ENTRY` (EGL_ENTRY(_r, _api, ...) _r (*_api)(**VA_ARGS**);) I believe. All over I am finding calls to the functions, or at least place holders for them, such as in `base/opengl/java/android/opengl/EGL14.java` where each entry point has a method prototype in the `EGL14` class. My java knowledge isn't that good so I am having a tough time finding the underlying device specific C functions.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction or quickly detail how the OpenGL stack is arranged on Android devices? Google is turning up dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you are going to find the implementations; they are likely proprietary graphics drivers so only available as binaries. The Java world just providing bindings into the vendor-specific native shared object.

Comment: So in the android world ARM (at least for by board given it's a Mali GPU) is providing a user-space binary blob? Where are these located?

Comment: Why are you looking for the entry point definitions? You can tell what extensions are present via the extension query string, and load them via `eglGetProcAddress()`.

Comment: I am trying to find (if at all possible) the entry point calls into the kernel so I can trace them. I am hoping to track buffer swaps from kernel space so that user space modification is not required.

Comment: What do the kernel entry points have to do with the user-space library entry points?

Comment: I am working my way down to the kernel and that's as far as I got when tracking back down through the code